# The source of ENSO data from NIST

Tags: dataset, nonlinear-regression

I'm using [ENSO dataset](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/nls/data/LINKS/DATA/ENSO.dat) from the NIST Statistical Reference Datasets as a test for nonlinear regression code. 
The data are monthly averaged atmospheric pressure differences between Easter Island and Darwin, called [Southern Oscillation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Ni%C3%B1o-Southern_Oscillation) Index (SOI). In the test, the data are fitted with three sine cycles ([like this](http://fityk.nieto.pl/_images/fityk-1.0.1-osx-so.png)).

I got curious about the Southern Oscillations and I started looking for more SOI data. I learned that there are a few different methods of how to calculate the SOI, but none of the other sources that I found (e.g. [here](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/current/soihtm1.shtml)) gives the same numbers are in the NIST StRD.

There is a reference in the dataset, *Numerical Methods and Software* by Kahaner, Moler and Nash, where I found only that the data are for years 1962-1975.
So my question is not really about statistics: how the ENSO dataset is related to the SOI data from other sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would not expect your two sets of numbers to be the same: the NIST numbers seem to be have been published to [test statistical software](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/general/bkground.html) while the Australian BOM numbers are designed to [identify whether the ENSO cycle is above or below average](http://www.bom.gov.au/climate/glossary/soi.shtml).

In particular the BOM numbers have been standardised to an index to have monthly seasonal factors removed, and for the remaining numbers to have a mean of around 0 and standard deviation around 10.   They may also have had corrections or improved sources used since the NIST numbers were published.

The NIST have had not had these proceses applied: in fact one of the purposes of the illustrated analysis is identifying the mean (coefficient `b1`) and the magnitude of the annual cycle (coefficients `b2` and `b3`).  It is possible that the NIST numbers are in real physical units (perhaps of pressure).

You might have hoped that there was a linear relationship between the two sets of numbers, for example between the January BOM numbers and data points 1, 13, 25, ... , 157 of the NIST numbers.  I did not spot it, though I did not try very hard.

Comment: +1 This excellent analysis demonstrates why the question is appropriate on this site.